# WinRT auto generated template compiling error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-runtime

I am new to c++/WinRT. I am trying to create a new blank project under c++/WinRT using Visual Studio Pro 2017. But it gives some compiling error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankApp2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd : warning C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd(1): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
1>midlrt : command line error MIDL1003: error returned by the C preprocessor (2)
1>Done building project "BlankApp2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I updated my Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version. I also used the latest WinRT. I could build a console application using the code in Kenny Kerr's command window sample code. But couldn't build the blank application created by the Visual Studio 2017 wizard. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The file mentioned in the message, it's one generated by Visual Studio? It's not a file you have copied from somewhere else?

Comment: No. It's all part of installation and auto generated files.

Comment: Has someone used some older version of Visual Studio 2017/WinRT with success? Would you please tell me what version combination did you use? Thank you.